# Weird mob in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image: video screenshot]

While watching [this](https://youtu.be/HfuB7qOBft4?t=750) HermitCraft episode, I noticed a red particle mob (visible in the screenshot).

The player hit the mob with his sword, causing it to erupt into a flame which was bigger in size than the flame which comes from a typical zombie, meaning this mob must be bigger than 1x1.

I don't know whether the game in the video was modded, or if any resource pack was used, but until now (after 51 episodes of HermitCraft) I've never seen such a strange phenomenon. Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: I have given the link to video to see the behaviour of the mob clearly. see at 12:30

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a spider with the Invisibility effect, noted by the invisible body except for the eyes. While in Hard mode and depending on local difficulty, they have a 20% chance of spawning with the Invisibility effect.

See also:

- [Spider spawning](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spider#Variants)
- [Local difficulty effects](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Difficulty#Attributes_affected_by_difficulty_conditions)

Comment: It seems that bubbles are also invisible. and only the player that is invisible can see them